# Improve font of an alert

Tags: bug, user-interface, popup

Whenever a user tries to comment and has under 50 reputation points, a little blue alert comes and says `You must have 50 rep. to comment.` the font of that alert is `"Times New Roman"`. Most alerts on Stack Overflow have a different font. Can the people at Stack Overflow fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for the >50 rep peasants? Thanks